# fonts.gstatic.com not appearing in Chrome Network Tab but it is in HAR file

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, performance-testing

If you look at the HAR file fonts.gstatic.com is present as is expected

However, it is not visible in the Google Chrome Network Tools tab (see sreenshot attached)[image: fonts.gstatic.com missing from Chrome Network Tab]

Is this a bug or am i missing something?

Comment: I don't see `fonts.gstatic.com` request on that page in Chrome 55 dev (normal + Incognito with no extensions), not in Fiddler debugger proxy, not in my saved HAR. Only fonts.googleapis.com that's also on your screenshot. So yeah, if you can reproduce it in a new Chrome person/profile then it's a bug that should be (or maybe already was) reported on https://crbug.com

Comment: if you test in in WebPageTest.com font.gstatic.com appears

Comment: Uhm, it's in response body and headers, there was no connection to that URL, so naturally it's not listed in the Network panel.

Answer (score 3):

In the HAR file we can see fonts.gstatic.com is in an HTTP response "Link" header value and content (i.e. CSS file).

The Link property doesn't actually fetch the source as the font is available locally, it won't try to load via url. 
For more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/src

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Pathway Gothic One';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('Pathway Gothic One'),local(PathwayGothicOne-Regular),url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/pathwaygothicone/v4/Lqv9ztoTUV8Q0FmQZzPqaBRcxZ7No-r1mAtcnpNU5cQ.woff2) format("woff2");
    unicode-range: U+0100-024F,U+1E00-1EFF,U+20A0-20AB,U+20AD-20CF,U+2C60-2C7F,U+A720-A7FF;
}
```